# specific formats using substrings and loops

Tags: java, string

I am trying to figure out how to make a certain string I get from the user format according to this sample format:

```
r     , e     , s     , u     , m     , e     , 
re    , es    , su    , um    , me    , 
res   , esu   , sum   , ume   , 
resu  , esum  , sume  , 
resum , esume , 
resume,
```

This is the code I have come up with so far but I am only able to get the first row correctly.
How would I accurately format my loops and print statements the way it's supposed to be?

```
public class Substrings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("\nPlease enter a word or q to quit: ");        
    String userWord = in.nextLine();
    for ( ; !userWord.equals("q") ; ){
        printSubstrings_a(userWord);  
        System.out.printf("\n\nPlease enter a word or q to quit: ");        
        userWord = in.nextLine();            
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nBye\n");   

}

public static void printSubstrings_a(String L)
{
    int N = L.length();
    String formatStr = "%-" + N + "s "+", ";

  for(int i = 0; i < L.length();i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < L.length();j++)
    {
        System.out.printf(formatStr,L.substring(j ,j+1));

    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things. It seems you want to discard one column per each row. So in the nested loop you have to reduce max count by one for each row. (you can say -1)

```
for(int j = 0; j < L.length() - i ;j++)
```

The second thing is you want to increase the the lenght of each column for each row:

L.substring(j ,j+1 + i)

but at some point you will have length above max and that can cause an error. Let's limit it by the string size. Also you already have a variable N=L.length(), so you can use it for all the loops, since it is an effectively final.

L.substring(j , Math.min(N,j+1 + i) )

and the final function could be this:

```
  public static void printSubstrings_a(String L) {
    final int N = L.length();
    final String formatStr = "%-" + N + "s " + ", ";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N - i; j++) {
        System.out.printf(formatStr, L.substring(j, Math.min(j + 1 + i, N)));

      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

It might be simpler to use the underlying characters and the first and last position when doing the formatting, though.